# Pretty Photo Lightbox / Videos on Mobile - Too Small

Tags: wordpress, mobile, video, lightbox, prettyphoto

This is related to a site I'm building in Wordpress. I am having trouble making Pretty Photo Lightbox work for small screened devices. By default it opens a very small and unuseable lightbox on phones. I've found several threads about how to fix it and none seem to do the trick. Has anyone here done this successfully? I am using it with the Justified Image Grid Plug-in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mobile detect from http://mobiledetect.net/

In my PHP file I include the mobile_detect.php

and check for mobile devices as follows:

```
<?php

include 'Mobile_Detect.php';

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

?>

//prettyPhoto js goes here
......




<a id="video_link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKhsb0bxuRo&rel=0" 
<?php

if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) { 
    echo ""; //hide from iphones and force iOS to open YouTube app instead
}elseif ($detect->isTablet){ 
    echo "rel=\"prettyPhoto\""; //show prettyPhoto on tablets
}else{ 
    echo "rel=\"prettyPhoto\""; //also show prettyPhoto popup on desktops
}

?>

 title=""><img src="images/play-video.png" alt="" title="" width="380" height="147" /></a>
```